# Can this dimmer really handle 144W?

Tags: dimmer, 24v

I was looking for a dimmer to control an LED strip with following characteristics:

- 5 meters long
- 14,4W (max) per meter, so 72W in total
- 24V

I found [a dimmer on ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/360754043934) that says it can handle 144W, which looks like this:
[image: ebay_dimmer]
I'm having a hard time believing something so small can handle that much power.
**My question is:** can it?
**Follow-up:** if so, how? Is this a custom chip? I've also read something about those things using Silicon-Controlled-Switches or Silicon-Controller-Rectifiers, something I know very little about, obviously.

Comment: with a 10mOhm FET, you would be dissipating 14 watts at 12 amperes in the on state. It is possible but I think that thing would get hot.

Comment: @HL-SDK 0.01 x 144 = 1.44 Watt, not 14.4

Comment: I'd be most concerned about the connector handling it.

Comment: Also, it's worth keeping in mind that whatever dissipation you determine, it only applies at 100% power (for a perfect switcher). Disregarding losses during transients, at 50% power it will only dissipate 50% of max. Of course, you can't actually disregard transient dissipation, so the whole thing gets more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can this dimmer really handle 144W?

144W at 24V = 6A.

If you PWM a FET so it is on or off it will dim LEDs that are connected using constant current or with a series resistors.

10 milliOhm Rdson FETS are easily enough available.

Power dissipation when on = I^2 x R = 6^2 x 0.01 = 0.36 Watts.
MOSFETS with 5 or 2 or even 1 milliOhm omnn resistance are available. 
Even 0.36 Watt would be acceptable.
So, yes-maybe. ie it's possible to design something that would.
Whether it does is TBD.
The price is right to find out :-).

Comment: Maybe they run it at 144W to shrink the "housing" onto the board.

Comment: are there standard circuits for something like this, or do these have to be custom designed? I'd love to see how they do it, starting from a say a 5V PWM signal (if it's not too much trouble) :)

Comment: @DaJF - very standard PWM control of a MOSFET is often 'good enough'. The FET is either on or off (except during transistions) so power dissipation is minimised. Simplistically, just applying an adequate level PWM signal to a MOSFET gate is what is required.